# regular expression to find the longest recurring character sequence in a line

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression to find the longest recurring character sequence in a line?

Comment: You don't. You just scan along the line using a loop or whatever. Why would you want to use a regular expression for this?

Comment: Just to muddy the waters; do *newlines* count as characters?  If they do do you want `\r\n` to count as two or does your platform only use `\n`?

Comment: @Aadith: wrong tool for the job. you don't use a ruler to measure speed, or a bathroom scale to measure temperature.

Comment: @stillstanding: This one made me laugh :)

Comment: trying to leverage regular expression search feature in notepad++ to look for certain patterns in a file..not really interested in writing a program for this

Comment: @stillstanding have read that regex can be used for such things...in perl at least..not been in touch with perl..

Comment: @stillstanding so that's why I still weigh 32 degrees!!

Comment: @Keng: Ignore CRLFs.  A vast, smart-wing conspiracy between the operating system, the tty driver, the system libraries, and your programming language effects the illusion that all textfiles have each line terminated with a logical newline character.

Comment: @Greg: Because, of course, that being a declarative programming language rather than an imperative one, regexes are the most intuitive and parsimonious approach to finding repeating sequences. You may however, combine their declarative-PL logic with imperative-PL logic as I provide in my first solution, or with functional-PL as I do in my other two.

Comment: @stillstanding: Don’t ever bet against what I can do with a Perl regex: that’s a sucker bet.

Comment: @tchrist - I didn't say that regex couldn't form part of the solution, but what was requested was a single regex to do the whole thing. My point was that *that* is a bad idea.

Comment: @Greg: I fully agree with you that it’s a bad idea. It’s *possible*, but not generally applicable outside Perl, because you have to invert the customary logic by embedding part of your normal program inside the regex one.  I think the imperative wrapper approach is just fine, but that may be my own bias: I imagine functional people like the other two techniques I mention.  I don’t care for them because they waste time storing more than they need to, which can begin to matter with longer input strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all relevant character sequences with the regular expression `/(.)\1*/`.

Finding the longest such sequence is best done using a tool other than regular expressions.

Comment: This will find *all* characters because of the * quantifier. You need a + instead.

Comment: @neo2862: That was intentional - the longest repeating sequence of characters in a (non-empty) string could in theory have length 1. You could for example use the regular expression I gave to first find the relevant substrings and then use ordinary program code to find the longest such one. That only works if you use `*` instead of `+`.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Is a single occurrence a repeating sequence? I'm curious. I mean... it is not really repeated, is it?

Comment: I think 'repeating' implies that there is at least two of the same character.

Comment: @neo2862: OK, I changed "repeating" to "relevant" but rather than a pointless terminology discussion, let's talk about the OPs problem. If the input string is "aaa" the answer is 3. If the input string is "aa" the answer is 2. If the input string is "a" the answer is what? If you think it's 0/undefined then use +. If you think it's 1 then use +.

Comment: Also, if the string is `"abc"`, all characters "repeat" once, you probably want to catch all, not none. And Mark, +1 on the comment, but the last character should be `*`. Typo.

Comment: @Kobi: Yes, the last character should be *, I can't edit it now unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

It’s easiest to do this in a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string = "this aaa and bbbb for ### ## ppppppp";
my $max = "";
while ($string =~ /((.)\2+)/gs) {
    $max = $1 if length($1) > length($max);
}
print "$max\n";
```

You could also use a `reduce`, but this is less efficient:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use List::Util "reduce";
my $string = "this aaa and bbbb for ### ## ppppppp";
my $max = reduce { length($b) > length($a) ? $b : $a } "", 
                    $string =~ /((.)\2+)/gs;
print "$max\n";
```

If you want it in just one assignment, that’s simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string = "this aaa and bbbb for ### ## ppppppp";
my $max = ( sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } "", $string =~ /((.)\2+)/g)[0];
print "$max\n";
```

All three answers produce `ppppppp` for that sample string.

They also return the empty string if there is no such sequence, and they return first such sequence in the event of a tie.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following regular expression to find repeating characters:

```
(.)\1+
```

but should use your programming language to properly determine the longest match.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, it's impossible to put state such as "longest" into a regular expression. The only thing you can do is make a regular expression, and have it match against the sequence. If it matches, get the length of recurring characters and make a longer regular expression that matches more characters. Keep doing this while you find matches.
This is a silly alternative of just writing a simple parser for the text.

In pseudo-code that parser could be:

```
for(i = beginning to end, i++) {
 recurring_length = recurring(i, 1);
 if(recurring_length > max)
     max = recurring_length;
}

function recurring(i, length) {
   if(i+1 != EOF && (character at i == character i+1) )
       return recurring(i+1, length + 1);
   else return length;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is an inefficient algorithm and can be optimized in some significant ways, it's just an illustration

Comment: Never say never: Perl abhors the word “can’t”. ☺ I can *certainly* do it in a single, wholly contained Perl regex. However, I prefer to use a hybrid approach.

Comment: It's simply not possible to model a variable finite repetition of characters in a regular grammar. Therefore you can't use a regular expression to map it. Note that in your perl examples you still need other control flows such as loops, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it's done in Python (no need for regular expressions):

```
>>> str = 'iamastriiiiiingwaitwaaaaaaaaaaaaaatttt'
>>> lchar = ''
>>> longest = 0
>>> cnt = 1
>>> for i in str:
    if lchar == i:
        cnt += 1
    else:
        cnt = 1
    if cnt > longest:
        longest = cnt
        longchar = i
    lchar = i

>>> longchar
'a'
>>> longest
14
```

And if you want to store it in a string (pretty simple):

```
>>> string = ''
>>> for x in range(longest):
    string += longchar

>>> string
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = 'ahhhhhhhhhhjjjjjjjiiiieeeeeeeeeeeeeeei';
my ($char, $long) = ('',0);
while($str=~/(.)\1*/g) {
    if (length $& > $long) {
        $long = length$&;
        $char = $1,
    }
}
say "$char : $long";
```

#### Output:

```
e : 15
```