# Find the longest section of repeating characters

Tags: java, string

Imagine a string like this:

`#*****~~~~~~**************~~~~~~~~***************************#`

I am looking for an elegant way to find the indices of the longest continues section that contains a specific character. Let's assume we are searching for the `*` character, then I expect the method to return the start and end index of the last long section of `*`.

I am looking for the elegant way, I know I could just bruteforce this by checking something like

```
indexOf(*)
lastIndexOf(*)
//Check if in between the indices is something else if so, remember length start from new 
//substring and repeat until lastIndex reached
//Return saved indices
```

This is so ugly brute-force - Any more elegant way of doing this? I thought about regular expression groups and comparing their length. But how to get the indices with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regular expression to find the longest recurring character sequence in a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335678/regular-expression-to-find-the-longest-recurring-character-sequence-in-a-line)

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly than an approach with regular expressions will not be better or worse then the programmatic approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Regex-based solution

If you don't want to **hardcode** a specific character like `*` and find *"Find the longest section of repeating characters"* as the title of the question states, then the proper *regular expression* for the section of repeated characters would be:

```
"(.)\\1*"
```

Where `(.)` a group that consists from of a single character, and `\\1` is a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) that refers to that group. `*` is greedy [quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html), which means that presiding backreference could be repeated zero or more times.

Finally, `"(.)\\1*"` captures a sequence of subsequent identical characters.

Now to use it, we need to compile the regex into `Pattern`. This action has a cost, hence if the regex would be used multiple times it would be wise to declare a constant:

```
public static final Pattern REPEATED_CHARACTER_SECTION = 
    Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*");
```

Using features of modern Java, the longest sequence that matches the above pattern could be found literally with a single line of code.

Since Java 9 we have method [`Matcher.results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) which return a stream of [`MatchResult`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html) objects, describe a matching group.

[`MatchResult.start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html#start()) [`MatchResult.end()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html#end()) expose the way of accessing start and end indices of the group. To extract the group itself, we need to invoke [`MatchResult.group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html#group(int)).

That how an implementation might look like:

```
public static void printLongestRepeatedSection(String str) {
    
    String longestSection = REPEATED_CHARACTER_SECTION.matcher(str).results() // Stream<MatchResult>
        .map(MatchResult::group)                                              // Stream<String>
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))                         // find the longest string in the stream
        .orElse(""); // or orElseThrow() if you don't want to allow an empty string to be received as an input
    
    System.out.println("Longest section:\t" + longestSection);
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void printLongestRepeatedSection(String str) {

    MatchResult longestSection = REPEATED_CHARACTER_SECTION.matcher(str).results() // Stream<MatchResult>
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(m -> m.group().length()))                     // find the longest string in the stream
        .orElseThrow(); // would throw an exception is an empty string was received as an input

    System.out.println("Section start:   " + longestSection.start());
    System.out.println("Section end:     " + longestSection.end());
    System.out.println("Longest section: " + longestSection.group());
}
```

*Output:*

```
Section start:   34
Section end:     61
Longest section: ***************************
```

***Links:***

- <sup>Official tutorials on [Lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) provided by Oracle</sup>
- <sup>A quick tutorial on [Regular expressions](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)</sup>

## Simple and Performant Iterative solution

You can do it without regular expressions by manually iterating over the indices of the given string and checking if the previous character matches the current one.

You just need to maintain a couple of variables denoting the start and the end of the longest previously encountered section, and a variable to store the starting index of the section that is being currently examined.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static void printLongestRepeatedSection(String str) {
    if (str.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    int maxStart = 0;
    int maxEnd = 1;
    
    int curStart = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i - 1)) {   // current and previous characters are not equal
            if (maxEnd - maxStart < i - curStart) { // current repeated section is longer then the maximum section discovered previously
                maxStart = curStart;
                maxEnd = i;
            }
            curStart = i;
        }
    }
    
    if (str.length() - curStart > maxEnd - maxStart) { // checking the very last section
        maxStart = curStart;
        maxEnd = str.length();
    }

    System.out.println("Section start: " + maxStart);
    System.out.println("Section end:   " + maxEnd);
    System.out.println("Section:   " + str.substring(maxStart,  maxEnd));
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "#*****~~~~~~**************~~~~~~~~***************************#";
    
    printLongestRepeatedSection(source);
}
```

*Output:*

```
Section start: 34
Section end:   61
Section:   ***************************
```

Comment: Okay, I simply used `Pattern.compile("\\*+".replace('*', token))`  to avoid the hardcoded part. But I see, using streams is definetly elegant. I like that you also provided the iterative performant solution but this part of code is not called very often so the more maintainable code is better. I will use the stream version you suggested. That looks really smooth

Answer (score 2):

Use methods of class `Matcher`.

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "#*****~~~~~~**************~~~~~~~~***************************#";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        int max = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int length = matcher.end() - matcher.start();
            if (length > max) {
                max = length;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

The regular expression searches for occurrences of one or more asterisk (`*`) characters.

Method `end` returns the index of the first character **after** the last character matched and method `start` returns the index of the first character matched. Hence the length is simply the value returned by method `end` minus the value returned by method `start`.

Each subsequent call to method `find` starts searching from the end of the previous match.

The only thing left is to get the longest string of asterisks.

Comment: This is useful. I did not know that matcher knows about start and end offsets. Nice. Thank you. Learned something new

Answer (score 1):

The solution based on the regular expression may use some features from Stream API to get an array of indexes of the longest sequence of a given character:

- `Pattern.quote` should be used to safely wrap the input character for the search within a regular expression
- `Stream<MatchResult>` returned by [`Matcher::results`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) provides necessary information about the start and end of the match
- [`Stream::max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) allows to select the longest matching sequence
- `Optional::map` and `Optional::orElseGet` help convert the match into the desired array of indexes

```java
public static int[] getIndexes(char c, String str) {
    return Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(Character.toString(c)) + "+")
        .matcher(str)
        .results()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(mr -> mr.end() - mr.start()))
        .map(mr -> new int[]{mr.start(), mr.end()})
        .orElseGet(() -> new int[]{-1, -1});
}

// Test:
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getIndexes('*', "#*****~~~~~~**************~~~~~~~~***************************#")));
// -> [34, 61]
```